# CMS for a review site

Tags: cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best CMS for review-type sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/best-cms-for-review-type-sites)

Hi,
what's the better CMS/theme for a review site? It will be a site about movie reviews from editors, and visitors should comment the review.
I'm looking for something simple to implement.

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) sounds ideal for this. It's designed for you to write content and users to comment on it. It's very easy to set up (it's install [famously only takes 5 minutes to do](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)) and it is very intuitive to use. Plus you can always customize it with lots of available [themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) and [plug-ins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) and updating it can be as easy as just a couple of clicks.

Comment: I read the question as "what is the best site for user-generated reviews", so this wouldn't be a very good fit.

Comment: I took "and visitors should comment *the* review" as visitors commenting on an existing review from an editor.

Answer (score 0):

WP easy to setup; but expect to spend lots of time for security measures.