# What are the best CMS's to use for a review-type website?

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

I'm looking for a CMS that I can use to build my user-generated review website.

The reviews are attached to a list of products. The products are added by the users themselves, and there needs to be a clever way of consolidating identical and duplicate products. Every review has multiple pre-determined fields which I, the admin, will configure. A couple of examples of the pre-determined fields includes a 5-star rating system, and multiple text fields each within a category type. Non-registered visitors can view the reviews on the products; registered users can write reviews for existing products but need to have had written X number of reviews before being able to add new products (that they or others can review for).

The latter criteria is probably very difficult to find in an existing CMS, and I'll probably have to develop it myself but I thought I would ask this community for a recommendation on the CMS to use that will get me closer to the review website I'm hoping to build.

Your help is appreciated.

PS: A similar question was asked over 4 years ago [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/best-cms-for-review-type-sites) but that was a very long time ago and new and better solutions may have come out since then.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the link. I've reviewed it prior to asking my question. I wasn't able to find what I needed from it.

Comment: Since you are after an opinion based answer, the mods are likely to close this question

Comment: There are too many options out there for me to give a definite answer. You should experiment with all the CMS's and scripts you know how to use. You may want to do a google search for scripts containing features you need.